# Apache mod_rewrite, .htaccess and virtual hosts conflicts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have 2 virtual hosts like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/watermelon/hhgt/webroot
ServerName booking
#ErrorLog logs/booking-error_log
#CustomLog logs/booking-access_log common
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:5321>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/watermelon/ik/webroot
    ServerName hotspot.local
    ErrorLog logs/hotsppot.local-error_log
    CustomLog logs/hotsppot.local-access_log common
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And they have same .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Sometimes the first vhost load the second's vhost index.php!

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using the correct port when loading `hotspot.local`. I.E. `http://hotspot.local:5321`?

Answer (score 1):

This could because your using a default in /etc/apache2/sites-available/

Check that you have setup the available sites correctly, furthermore check the Apache logs in /var/logs/apache2